# MPAndroidChart Label inside Bar

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using an HorizontalBarChart I want to draw a Label (the name of the vendor) inside or in the middle of the Bar, in the BarDaset there is something called setLabel but it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
 private BarDataSet createLineChart(String storeName, List<String> listofcompanies){

    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries= new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    for (int j = 0; j < listofcompanies.size(); j++) {
        entries.add(new   BarEntry(Float.parseFloat(listofcompanies.get(j)),j));

    }
    Random rd = new Random();
    setComp1 = new BarDataSet(entries,storeName);
    setComp1.setColor(Color.argb(255,rd.nextInt(256),rd.nextInt(256),rd.nextInt(256)));
           setComp1.setDrawValues(true);
    setComp1.setLabel(storeName);
    setComp1.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    setComp1.setDrawValues(true);
    // LineData data =new LineData(labels,dataset);
    return setComp1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
```

Or

```
chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxisPosition.TOP_INSIDE);
```

**This will solve your problem.**